# RDLC C# Winform/WPF Print two copies on same page for File/Audit reasons

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rdlc

This is a very specific issue I am having. I have a need to print two (or three, or four) copies of the exact same report on the same page.

The reason, is that Invoice are pre formatted, and for audit reasons creates multiples copies on the same page. So every time I print a new Invoice, I need to print on the same page multiple copies that is defined by the customer.

here is what I have tried:
1) Try to make two copies, but the printer mistakes it for two pages, so spits out the page before it prints out.
2) Try to push everything into the body. At first this idea is very promising. But the body grows when the Tablix grows. If I can solve this issue, then the problem resolves itself.

Can anybody help??

Comment: You state you need multiple copies ON THE  SAME PAGE.  OR... Do you need multiple copies 1 per each page.  Ex: An invoice may take an entire page.  I would have to assume you wanted TWO identical copies each on their own respective sheet of paper.  Is this more accurate to your needs of multiple copies?  Otherwise, 2, 3, 4 and more on the SAME page you would need magnifying glass to read.   Please confirm a COPY, not all within a single page.

Comment: multiples copies on same page. LIke one sheet of paper can have two or tree copies of the same report. Ex. Customer Copy, File Copy, Accountant Copy, etc.

Comment: What is the MAXIMUM HEIGHT size for a single invoice to be printed.  Is it like a fixed header size summarizing who, date, amount due, etc or can it grow based on underlying details making it virtually impractical to do if you have 100 line items being generated on an invoice.

Comment: I have tried that rout, but with Max Height, the tablix would just jump to another page if surpassed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and now benefit, I took a shortcut solution:

Here is what we did:

1) Moved all items into the body. This allowed us to copy the elements over again as many time as necessary inside the page/body height and width.
2) In the codebehind, added a parameter that asked for MaxRow for the detail. Based on that, how ever many rows I had in the actual invoice, the code would just add blank rows to complete the MaxRow number.

So if my Max Row is 15. And my invoice has 2 rows, the system would just create 13 blank rows. If in another invoice, I had 10 rows, the system would just create 2 blank rows.

With that little short cut, I would always have the same tablix size, and therefore always maintain the same body size.

Comment: Oh and also... in this particular scenario, since these are pre-printed forms that need to be filled out. We would never have more than 15 Rows. So that would never be the case.